# Error With ContactForm Plugin - Internal Server Error

Tags: plugins, emails, plugin-contactform

Using,
https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm

I recently migrated the server to a new server and now i get:

```
2015/12/03 19:21:27 [error] [exception.phpmailerException] exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php:1256 Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1100): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 3 De...', 'This is a multi...')
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php(1004): PHPMailer->postSend()
#2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\services\EmailService.php(435): PHPMailer->send()
#3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\services\EmailService.php(77): Craft\EmailService->_sendEmail(Object(Craft\UserModel), Object(Craft\EmailModel), Array)
#4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\plugins\contactform\services\ContactFormService.php(54): Craft\EmailService->sendEmail(Object(Craft\EmailModel))
#5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\plugins\contactform\controllers\ContactFormController.php(100): Craft\ContactFormService->sendMessage(Object(Craft\ContactFormModel))
#6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\ContactFormController->actionSendMessage()
#7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#9 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#10 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('sendMessage')
#11 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(805): CWebApplication->runController('contactForm/sen...')
#12 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\etc\web\WebApp.php(275): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#13 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#14 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\craft\app\index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#15 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\index.php(14): require_once('C:\inetpub\wwwr...')
#16 {main} REQUEST_URI=/contact HTTP_REFERER=https://soho.infor.com/contact
--- 2015/12/03 19:21:27 [error] [application] SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Is, Some application not installed? Or something not configured? Or could it be a matter that this site requires authentication now to hit it in the browser (https redirects)?

Additionally where is the SMTP server configured?

-Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft's email SMTP settings are configured under Settings->Email in the control panel.

The error message you're getting:

```
2015/12/03 19:21:27 [error] [exception.phpmailerException] exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP connect() failed.
```

Simply means that PHP/Craft can't connect (for whatever reason) to the server you specified with whatever SMTP settings you've entered in Settings->Email.

Chances are the credentials are invalid or the settings are incorrect, but it can also happen is something (firewall, router, etc.) is blocking output SMTP access as well.